# Error(1): component conversion failed: fast_xml_parser_1.XMLBuilder is not a constructor

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, salesforce, sfdx, fast-xml-parser

Erorr(1):  component conversion failed: fast_xml_parser_1.XMLBuilder is not a constructor.

Jenkins job using SFDx Cli for deployment purpose. but it is getting fail on the same validation or check-only stage.

Earlier jobs were getting successfully completed.

I have tried to bring on SFDx stable version. Installed fast_xml_parser using npm command. but no luck.

Comment: I have tried below steps and it worked.

-Uninstalled current SFDX cli from Jenkins server
-Download latest SFDx cli and install.
-Jenkins will start working as expected.